# Trimming a java string based on string values?

Tags: java, if-statement, string-formatting, indexof

I have a database query that returns some string data in a column.  I would like to trim this field based on whether a particular string exists in the data?

If the string contains a comma ",", I'm looking to return LEFT of that first comma
If the string contains a hypen "-", I would like to return LEFT of that first hypen
If the string contains neither, I would like to return the first 14 characters of the string?

I am headed in this direction at the moment:

```
StringHandling.LEFT(row1.DESCRIPTION,StringHandling.INDEX(row1.DESCRIPTION,"-"))
```

How can I include some logic to check for the comma or lack thereof and return the appropriate substring in my expression??

Thanks so much!

Comment: You should re-check your database design.......... :-|

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (Edited to handle `null`)

```
public static String specialTrim(String input) {
    if (input == null)
        return null; // or return "", or whatever else you want
    if (input.contains(","))
        return input.substring(0, input.indexOf(","));
    if (input.contains("."))
        return input.substring(0, input.indexOf("."));
    return input.substring(0, Math.min(14, input.length()));
}
```

The `Math.min()` is to handle when the string is less than 14 characters long.

Comment: Nearly, just remove the '-1'.

Comment: Bohemian, your code works PERFECTLY! As you can see I am still finding my way with programming!  I understand your code entirely but lack the necessary knowledge with regards to how it is structured to write it myself!  I know it's a problem when a question starts to fork off but can I add a twist?  How could I include null handling?If the string was null that it return as such?

Comment: yes, minus the '-1' and changing the "." to "-"...but I'm choking on Null pointer exceptions now..doh!

Comment: @Bohemian getting to grips with the mini markdown so as to notify you of my earlier feedback

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (I stole Bohemian's Math.min() technique ;-)) :

```
 public String dbString(String s){
        String[] parts = s.split("(,|-)");

        String trimmed = parts.length > 1? parts[0] : parts[0].substring(0, Math.min(14,  parts[0].length());

        return trimmed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the API for String.contains, String.indexOf, and String.substring.

```
String theString = <wherever it comes from>;
// if it contains a ,
if (theString.contains(",")) {
    // return all elements one position to the left
    return theString.substring(0, theString.indexOf(",") - 1);
} else // and repeat
```